# Loop over variables in Lisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

I wrote the function

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((str1 "foo") (str2 "bar"))
    (loop for s in '(str1 str2) do (message s))))
```

but it does not work. The Elisp *Backtrace* message is:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp str1)

How can I make it work?

P.S.: the following modified version works perfectly, but I need the original version

```
(defun test1 ()
  (loop for s in '("asdf" "fdsa") do (message s)))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `quote` operator (for which the apostrophe is syntactic sugar) means that its arguments are not evaluated, i.e. `(quote (str1 str2))` returns a list of two *symbols*.  Use `list` instead: `(list str1 str2)`.

Answer (score 6):

Build a list of the values:

```
(defun test ()
  (let ((str1 "foo") (str2 "bar"))
    (loop for s in (list str1 str2) do (message s))))
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
`(,str1 ,str2)
```

Comment: A bit complex -- a simeple
   (list str1 str2)
would do as well